# Ошибка при выполнении кода в lms SyntaxError pep8?

Tags: python

При выполнении кода в системе lms выдается ошибка

```
print("Какой ваш любимый знак зодиака? 1. Овен 2. Козерог 3. Стрелец 4. Скорпион 5. Дева Ответ цифрой")
a = input()
if a == "1" or a == "2" or a == "3" or a == "4" or a == "5":
    ar1 = ["Вы любите овенов", "Вы любите козерогов", "Вы любите стрелецов", "Вы любите скорпионов", "Вы любите дев!"]
    ans1 = ar1[int(a)]
    print("Какие цветы вы выберите? 1. Лилии, 2. Тюльпаны, 3. Розы, 4. Хризантемы, 5. Пионы. Ответ дайте просто цифрой.")
    b = input()
    if b == "1" or b == "2" or b == "3" or b == "4" or b == "5":
        ar2 = ["Вы любите лилии!", "Вы любите тюльпаны!", "Вы любите розы!", "Вы любите хризантемы!", "Вы любите пионы!"]
        ans2 = ar2[int(b)]
        print(ans1)
        print(ans2)
    else:
        print("Ваш ответ некорректный")
else:
    print("Ваш ответ некорректный")
```

Ошибка:

> > 

stdout:
/bin/sh ./build.sh 1>&2

stderr:
solution.py:4:120: E999 SyntaxError: invalid syntax
Код не соответствует стандарту PEP8
или в нем есть синтаксические ошибки
make: *** [Makefile:2: build] Error 1

Comment: каков же вопрос? И на заметку: нумерация в списке начинается с 0, а не с 1.

Comment: @Эникейщик, почему ошибка синтаксиса?

Comment: в нем нет ошибки синтаксиса

Comment: Онлайновый `pep8` чекер говорит на этот код, что строки не должны быть длиннее 79 символов.

Answer (score 1):

PEP8 - это стандарт по которому *рекомендуется* писать Python-код, но не обязательно. Если его не соблюдать, то компилятор просто высветит слабые предупреждения. Однако в некоторых системах (преимущественно учебных), предупреждения распознаются как ошибки. Конкретно в вашем случае, скорее всего, ругается на длину этих строк:

```
print("Какие цветы вы выберите? 1. Лилии, 2. Тюльпаны, 3. Розы, 4. Хризантемы, 5. Пионы. Ответ дайте просто цифрой.")
```

```
ar2 = ["Вы любите лилии!", "Вы любите тюльпаны!", "Вы любите розы!", "Вы любите хризантемы!", "Вы любите пионы!"]
```

Обе выходят за ограничение в 120 символов (входит в стандарт PEP8) всего на 1 символ, так что можно попробовать просто написать:

```
print("
  *ваш текст*"
)
...
ar2 = [
  *элементы массива*
]
```

Если в вашем редакторе максимальная длина строки меньше, то можно по обрезать еще разбив строки, например так:

```
if a == "1"\
        or a == "2"\
        or a == "3":
...
print("Первая часть текста",
      "вторая",
      "третья")
...
ar1 = [
    "Элемент",
    "Еще один",
    "И еще"
]
```

Comment: Кстати да, там же пробелы, в этом случае и правда проще и понятнее использовать `print` с запятыми.

Answer (score 0):

Проверил двумя онлайн-чекерами на соответствие `PEP8`. Тут только одна проблема со стандартом - строки длиннее 79 символов. Таких строк тут 4.

Теперь, как это починить на примере части кода. Чиним длинную строку в кавычках, разбивая её на подстроки в кавычках. Хотя, возможно, для читабельности следовало бы именно в отдельных строках текст выводить, я просто показываю вам, как тот же самый результат получить без нарушения `PEP8`:

```py
print("Какой ваш любимый знак зодиака? "
      "1. Овен 2. Козерог 3. Стрелец 4. Скорпион 5. Дева "
      "Ответ цифрой")
```

А длинный список чиним переносом каждого элемента на отдельную строку:

```py
    ar1 = ["Вы любите овенов",
           "Вы любите козерогов",
           "Вы любите стрелецов",
           "Вы любите скорпионов",
           "Вы любите дев!"]
```

Кстати, проверки можно сделать гораздо короче:

```py
if a in list("12345"):
```

Ну и, как вам уже сказали, индексация списков в питоне начинается `0`, поэтому нужно вычесть `1` из ответа прежде чем обращаться к элементу списка:

```py
ans1 = ar1[int(a) - 1]
```